# How to get next Date with specific time in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I want to get the date with specific day and time in PHP, like i want the date of next day and time of 9.30 am i.e "2011-06-02 09:30:00". 
the code i was using get to do that,

```
<?php
   $next_day_date = date("Y")."-".date("m")."-".(date("d")+1)."  09:30:00";
   $new_trig_time_stamp = strtotime($next_day_date);
   $trigger_date_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$new_trig_time_stamp);
   echo $trigger_date_time;
?>
```

the code above works fine but fails on 31 day, on 31st it returns "1970-01-01 05:30:00".
Is there any other way to do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When shifting dates by a fixed number, it's better to use `mktime()`, because it handles invalid dates well (e.g. it knows that January 32 is in fact February 1)

```
$trigger_date_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(9,30,0, date('n'), date('j')+1, date('Y'));
```

Answer (score 3):

`strtotime()` is very useful here.

```
$trigger_date_time = date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime( "tomorrow 9:30" ) );
```

Comment: It’s not necessarily tomorrow, though. The next 09:30 might be a few minutes from now, and this solution would provide the wrong answer in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate it via unix timestamp - much less annoyance

```
<?php
   $trigger_date_time = date("Y-m-d 09:30:00",time() + 60*60*24);
   echo $trigger_date_time;
?>
```

Comment: yeah it worked even tried for the May 31. it worked... thanks! strtotime() was creating problem in my case.

Comment: This solution with manual second adjustment would fail when clocks are shifted because of DST (once a year it would give 1h too late and once 1h to early).

Comment: If precision of solution is in days, hour doesn't matter

Answer (score 1):

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day')) . ' 09:30:30';
```

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say it's because there's no explanation provided with the code.

Comment: And why did others get downvotes? (I think everyone got at the same time)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`date_add`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.date-add.php).

In more detail, something like...

```
$myDate = new DateTime("Some time");
$myDate->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
```

You can then use `$myDate->format(…)` to extract formatted representations.