# PHP - Send notification every 30 minutes without using cron

Tags: php, sql

Hello I've read other post related on this but still not closed on my case.

I want to send a notification on my client `5` times every 30 minutes after they successfully created their `Application number`. I have a table column `Creation_date` which save a `date time` format of `2018-09-17 11:00:00` and `Send_attempts` which will update every time it sends a notification. Should I add another column, get its `creation date`, add every 30 minutes, and stop until it reaches its `5th` attempts? Its really confusing for my part. Any help is fully appreciated. thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [creating schedule task without Cron job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028783/creating-schedule-task-without-cron-job)

Answer (score 1):

You can create another column named "update_date" (other than creation_date and send_attempts), which will keep the updated date-time of each successful attempt. So you'll keep checking the update_date field for 30 minutes to execute another attempt till 5th and on each attempt you'll update the date-time of "update_date" field.

I hope it'll help you.